# Calling custom command to set a value in a custom environment doesn't work

Tags: macros, environments, minipage

I'm trying to create a custom environment that takes care of positioning certain pieces of information at certain coordinates within a minipage. The positioning works fine, however I try to provide the information through commands bound to the environment to be able to separate the kinds of information, which looks something like this:

```
\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{
% \givenchsskills functions as a variable of sorts; its initial value is "original value"
\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
% \chsskills is used to set the variable by renewing the command \givenchsskills and having it return the argument. 
% Double # because we're in an environment that also uses arguments.
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenchsskills}{##1}}

% Stuff concerning positioning
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

% This adjustbox serves the sole purpose of providing a background image. The latter is the reason for the weird positioning values.
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}, bgimage=bg_sheet.png}

% Textblocks allow for positioning relative to the environments coordinates. \fboxsep0pt is used to prevent box separation in the combination of minipage and mbox...
\begin{textblock}{5}(2.15,.8)\fboxsep0pt
% ... which i'm using to prevent linebreaks and still be able to position the text. Probably messy; I'm far from being a clean LaTeX user... Anyway, this prints the argument for the environment.
\begin{minipage}[t][.57cm][c]{8.8cm}\mbox{\large #1}\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}

% Positioning of the main content for this environment which itself is wrapped inside a minipage the restricts it to a certain size box. Kind of.
\vspace{2.8cm}
\hspace{.8cm}
\begin{minipage}[t][6.6cm]{7.5cm}
}
{
\end{minipage}

% Another textblock for positioning
\begin{textblock}{5}(.8,2)\fboxsep0pt
% This is merely to help me with finetuning the actual position by eyeing it. I can still see the background and the colored bounding box that will contain the text.
\transparent{.5}\colorbox{green}{
\begin{minipage}[t][.4cm][c]{10.1cm}
% This is where we get to the problem! This will print "original value", no matter if \chsskills has been used or not.
\givenchsskills
\end{minipage}
}
\end{textblock}
\end{adjustbox}
}
```

A sample use of the environment:

```
\begin{chs}{Some argument}
    Test content
    \chsskills{new value}
\end{chs}
```

As indicated by the comments in the code above, this will print the argument just fine. The content will appear too; however, instead of "new value", "original value" is printed.

If I simplify the environment a lot, the value will, however, be "new value", as intended:

```
\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{
\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenchsskills}{##1}}
Argument: #1\\
}
{
\\
Skills: \givenchsskills
}
```

This leaves me clueless as to what I may be doing wrong.

I'm happy to provide any more details as requested.

### Update

Right now, it looks like the issue may be caused by grouping that's broken once a minipage is added that wraps the main content of the environment, like so:

```
\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{
\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenchsskills}{##1}}
Argument: #1\\
Skills: \givenchsskills\\
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
}
{
\end{minipage}
}
```

Using `\gdef` instead of `\renewcommand` did not change anything for me:

```
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\gdef\givenchsskills{##1}}
```

As per [Ulrike Fischer's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373844/calling-custom-command-to-set-a-value-in-a-custom-environment-doesnt-work#comment924469_373844), here's a complete example using `\gdef` that doesn't work for me:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{
\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\gdef\givenchsskills{##1}}
Argument: #1\\
Skills: \givenchsskills\\
\begin{minipage}{8cm}
}
{
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{chs}{Some argument}
    Test content
    \chsskills{new value}
\end{chs}
\end{document}
```

### Update 2(.5)

Code example for the original problem with the usage of the command moved to the very end of the environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{transparent}

\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{\renewcommand{\givenchsskills}{#1}}
\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}, bgimage=bg_sheet.png}
\begin{textblock}{5}(2.15,.8)\fboxsep0pt
\begin{minipage}[t][.57cm][c]{8.8cm}\mbox{\large #1}\end{minipage}
\end{textblock}
\vspace{2.8cm}
\hspace{.8cm}
\begin{minipage}[t][6.6cm]{7.5cm}
}
{
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
\givenchsskills
}

\begin{document}
\begin{chs}{Some argument}
    Test content
    \chsskills{new value}
\end{chs}

\begin{chs}{Some argument}
    Test content
    \chsskills{newest value}
\end{chs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `\\ ` to break lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60092/discussion-between-cfr-and-koala).

Comment: Yes, I meant `\newcommand{\chsskills}{\gdef\givenchsskills{#1}}`, it was a typo, and I forgot to mention to define it outside of the `chs` environment

Comment: Without the latter part, it didn't work indeed. @cfr pointed this out to me, so now it works! I'm not sure how to go about answering the question now though (as in, answer so it's marked "answered").

Comment: @koala: I think you should redesign the whole environment anyway and leave this 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `\gdef` trick, in addition to putting `\newcommand` outside the environment. So I have

```
\newcommand{\givenchsskills}{original value}
\newcommand{\chsskills}[1]{%
  \gdef\givenchsskills{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{chs}[1]
{%
  \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}%
  \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}%
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\textheight]{\textwidth}, bgimage=example-image-a}%
    \begin{textblock}{5}(2.15,.8)\fboxsep0pt%
      \begin{minipage}[t][.57cm][c]{8.8cm}\mbox{\large #1}\end{minipage}%
    \end{textblock}%
    \vspace{2.8cm}%
    \hspace{.8cm}%
    \begin{minipage}[t][6.6cm]{7.5cm}%
    }{%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{adjustbox}\par
  \givenchsskills
}
```

Then it works without error and I get 'new value' and 'newest value' respectively at the end of the environments.

But note that `\givenchsskills` will give the current value outside the environment, too. If you don't want that, you can `\gdef` it to original value or `\relax` at the very end of the environment.